# uniqueness of Hodge decomposition

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, hodge-theory

Is it true that there is some kind of uniqueness associated with a Hodge decomposition.

E.G. if X and X' have isomorphic Hodge decomposition:($H^i(X,\mathbb{C})= \oplus_{p+q=i}H^{pq}(X)$)
$\cong$ ($H^i(X',\mathbb{C})= \oplus_{p+q=i}H^{pq}(X'))$, then $H^{pq}(X)\cong H^{pq}(X')$?

Comment: what is your notion of isomorphic in this case? I believe you can have isomorphisms of vector spaces between $H^i(X,\mathbb C)$ and $H^i(X',\mathbb C)$ that need not respect the Hodge structures.

Comment: You can assume vector spaces I think; anyways, check out propositiono 17.2.1 from Arapura's book: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-1809-2_17. The restriction map is an isomorphism $H_q(\mathbb{P}^n, \Omega^p) \rightarrow H^q(X,\Omega^p)$ provided p+q<n-1...It seems to assume some kind of uniqueness.

Comment: I don't have access to this book, but it sounds like the Lefschetz hyperplane theorem. I suppose we should clarify how $X$ and $X'$ are related. Do they have the same dimension? Are they embedded inside the same $\mathbb{P}^n$? And even with that isomorphism, I'm still worried about the degree where Lefschetz hyperplane theorem fails.

Comment: if you don't have access to the book, also consider: http://www.math.purdue.edu/~dvb/preprints/partIII.pdf proposition 15.2.1 by the same author.

Comment: What do you mean by uniqueness ? I mean, if you have a projective variety $X$, there is one and only one Hodge decomposition on its cohomology. If you have two isomorphics varieties, their Hodge decomposition are the same via the isomorphism between their cohomology. However, there are examples of homeomorphic varieties (so with same betti numbers) with different Hodge numbers. There are also examples of varieties with same Hodge numbers, and isomorphic cohomology groups, but with different Hodge decomposition.

Comment: @Roland can you explain why **projective varieties** have one and only one Hodge decomposition?

Comment: This is a result that the subgroup $H^{pq}\subset H^{p+q}(X,\mathbb{C})$ does not depend on any Kähler metrics. So there is only one decomposition.

Comment: @Roland; sorry, I don't follow

Comment: @user352102 So, this probably means that I didn't get your question. If you want to ask if on a vector space $H^n$ we can put several Hodge structures, this is certainly true. But on the cohomology of a projective variety, there is only one we want to consider.

Comment: @Roland, For compact Kahler manifolds X, the Hodge decomposition of X only depends on its structure as a complex manifold and not the Kahler metric on it. Why should a "nonsingular hypersurface defined by a degree d polynomial" subset of r-projective space necessarily have the same complex manifold structure as r-projective space it is sitting in? I guess you are saying that r-projective space has only one complex structure on it or something...?

Comment: @user352102 Take a torus, you can put several complex structures on it. And as a matter of fact, the Hodge structure on its cohomology will depend on the chosen complex structure. Now a complex torus embeds as a degree 3 curve in $\mathbb{P}^2$, but different complex structures yield different embedding. I am not saying that an hypersurface $X$ will have "the same" complex structure as $\mathbb{P}^n$, just that they have a unique complex structure such that the inclusion $X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^n$ is holomorphic. But different embeddings lead to different complex structures and Hodge structure